# Connection pooling for non-database server to server communication in Java

Tags: java, http, post, get, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to set up a server to server communication system.

Sever A communicates to B to gather B's information. These are low level HTTP calls (GET, POST, etc + Header and XML information) for different resources http://server.com/doc ..server/file ..server/folder etc

While I haven't tested this yet on large number of requests, we are looking at 1,000/s of requests per minute.

While I've seen some resources for JDBC, what are some non-database connection pooling tools available that would speed these transactions up?

Right now we are doing things similar to this:

```
URL url = new URL(ServerURL+ "connection");
HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
setAuthHeaders(connection);//custom function self explanatory
System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode()
connection.disconnect();
```

We cannot send multiple (different userbased) requests without creating a new URL and reconnecting to the server.

Is there a way to use the base ServerURL and then access a specific resource as needed with a specific GET, DELETE, POST..etc function?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the Apache HTTP Client project, I'm not aware of any benchmarks off the top of my head, but they do have much more extensive HTTP support than the 'raw' URL class.

You can then look into "Persistent HTTP Connections", they will create their own sort of overhead and could be difficult to configure, however if you need the speed then they may come in handy.